# How to create an infinite horizontal image marquee that fills the width of the viewport with copies of its children?

Tags: javascript, html, css, webflow

I’m trying to setup an image marquee on [my website](https://pizza-heroes.webflow.io/#pre-sale) that scrolls horizontally to the left. It’s using JavaScript code from [this guy](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex2/crawler/index.htm) to duplicate the images inside the marquee so that the marquee never has to stop.

I need a different marquee in each of the 4 chest tabs. Everything seemed to be working in the first tab until I added the other marquees in the other tabs. Now all but one of the marquees scroll infinitely. The rest stop duplicating their images and the marquees disappear off the screen. Here is a screenshot of the bug, the marquees other than the first one you see when the page loads stop duplicating their images and become empty:
[image of bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDo3E.jpg)

This only happens on my published website, not in the Stack Snippet. Yet the code seems to be the same. What do I need to change about this code to make all the tabs work?

And is there a way to make the JavaScript duplicate enough copies of the images inside the marquee to automatically fill the width of the viewport? So, if I only put three images they will be duplicated (in order) until the viewport is filled, and it will scroll like this to the left, infinitely.

Stack Snippet:

```js
for (let i = 1; i < 5; i += 1) {
  marqueeInit({
    uniqueid: `crawler-${i}`,
    style: {
      'height': '124px',
    },
    inc: 5,
    mouse: 'cursor driven',
    moveatleast: 2,
    neutral: 150,
    savedirection: true,
    random: false
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://codepen.io/ali-z/pen/XQoVQQ.js"></script>

<div class="marquee-wrapper">
  <div id="crawler-1" class="marquee">
    <img src="https://assets.website-files.com/5cbaabcccbd2ed57cddf7c9a/5cbd6352066183fcd219e067_hat.png" class="slider-image">
    <img src="https://assets.website-files.com/5cbaabcccbd2ed57cddf7c9a/5cbd637bfad96ca97f9b5685_armor.png" class="slider-image">
    <img src="https://assets.website-files.com/5cbaabcccbd2ed57cddf7c9a/5cbd6384ef4522dfba912d6b_crown.png" class="slider-image">
    <img src="https://assets.website-files.com/5cbaabcccbd2ed57cddf7c9a/5cbd6352066183fcd219e067_hat.png" class="slider-image">
    <img src="https://assets.website-files.com/5cbaabcccbd2ed57cddf7c9a/5cbd637bfad96ca97f9b5685_armor.png" class="slider-image">
    <img src="https://assets.website-files.com/5cbaabcccbd2ed57cddf7c9a/5cbd6384ef4522dfba912d6b_crown.png" class="slider-image">
  </div>

  <div id="crawler-2" class="marquee">
    <img src="https://assets.website-files.com/5cbaabcccbd2ed57cddf7c9a/5cbd6352066183fcd219e067_hat.png" class="slider-image">
    <img src="https://assets.website-files.com/5cbaabcccbd2ed57cddf7c9a/5cbd637bfad96ca97f9b5685_armor.png" class="slider-image">
    <img src="https://assets.website-files.com/5cbaabcccbd2ed57cddf7c9a/5cbd6384ef4522dfba912d6b_crown.png" class="slider-image">
    <img src="https://assets.website-files.com/5cbaabcccbd2ed57cddf7c9a/5cbd6352066183fcd219e067_hat.png" class="slider-image">
    <img src="https://assets.website-files.com/5cbaabcccbd2ed57cddf7c9a/5cbd637bfad96ca97f9b5685_armor.png" class="slider-image">
    <img src="https://assets.website-files.com/5cbaabcccbd2ed57cddf7c9a/5cbd6384ef4522dfba912d6b_crown.png" class="slider-image">
  </div>
  <div id="crawler-3" class="marquee">
    <img src="https://assets.website-files.com/5cbaabcccbd2ed57cddf7c9a/5cbd6352066183fcd219e067_hat.png" class="slider-image">
    <img src="https://assets.website-files.com/5cbaabcccbd2ed57cddf7c9a/5cbd637bfad96ca97f9b5685_armor.png" class="slider-image">
    <img src="https://assets.website-files.com/5cbaabcccbd2ed57cddf7c9a/5cbd6384ef4522dfba912d6b_crown.png" class="slider-image">
    <img src="https://assets.website-files.com/5cbaabcccbd2ed57cddf7c9a/5cbd6352066183fcd219e067_hat.png" class="slider-image">
    <img src="https://assets.website-files.com/5cbaabcccbd2ed57cddf7c9a/5cbd637bfad96ca97f9b5685_armor.png" class="slider-image">
    <img src="https://assets.website-files.com/5cbaabcccbd2ed57cddf7c9a/5cbd6384ef4522dfba912d6b_crown.png" class="slider-image">
  </div>
  <div id="crawler-4" class="marquee">
    <img src="https://assets.website-files.com/5cbaabcccbd2ed57cddf7c9a/5cbd6352066183fcd219e067_hat.png" class="slider-image">
    <img src="https://assets.website-files.com/5cbaabcccbd2ed57cddf7c9a/5cbd637bfad96ca97f9b5685_armor.png" class="slider-image">
    <img src="https://assets.website-files.com/5cbaabcccbd2ed57cddf7c9a/5cbd6384ef4522dfba912d6b_crown.png" class="slider-image">
    <img src="https://assets.website-files.com/5cbaabcccbd2ed57cddf7c9a/5cbd6352066183fcd219e067_hat.png" class="slider-image">
    <img src="https://assets.website-files.com/5cbaabcccbd2ed57cddf7c9a/5cbd637bfad96ca97f9b5685_armor.png" class="slider-image">
    <img src="https://assets.website-files.com/5cbaabcccbd2ed57cddf7c9a/5cbd6384ef4522dfba912d6b_crown.png" class="slider-image">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: HTML element `id`s are meant to be unique in your page. Give each crawler a unique `id` (i.e.: `crawler-1`, `crawler-2`,...) and replace the init with a for loop. Here's your [updated pen](https://codepen.io/andrei-gheorghiu/pen/eoXmGy).

Comment: Your question was put on hold because you are supposed to include the relevant part of code ***in the question itself***. An external link to a codepen/fiddle is not acceptable as that can be modified and/or deleted, leaving your question irrelevant, thus unfit for helping future visitors with a similar problem.

Comment: Thanks @AndreiGheorghiu each marquee does have a unique id on my website. I've updated my question so it uses Stack Snippets instead of Codepen and I've included an image of the bug. A screen recording of the bug can be found here: https://cl dot ly/1fbc08bc47fa

Comment: I've already voted for re-opening your question, but I can't answer it before enough people vote on it being reopen. Following the same principle as above, unless you recreate the bug here, your question is off-topic and should not be answered. ***Because*** if it's answered there will be no way for anyone with a similar issue to see your initial problem, since by that time your website won't display it anymore.

Comment: I also strongly advise against incrementally changing your question based on provided suggestions. For example, because you now included my suggestion in your question without clearly making the distinction between it and the initial question, you make it look like I'm suggesting solutions that have already been applied. Besides, you make it impossible for anyone having similar problems to follow the same path towards a solution as you did. In principle, I only want to help **you** if I can also help anyone ***like you*** at the same time.

Comment: You don't seem to understand the importance of unique ids. The whole purpose of the `uniqueId` parameter of your initializer is ***that it matches the unique `id` of the element in the page it controls***. Replace `<div class="marquee1">` with `<div id="crawler1">`, `<div class="marquee2">` with `<div id="crawler2">`, etc... and it will work **with what you currently have**. Also, note the for loop solution I suggested above is supposed to replace all the individual, separate init scripts with only 1. If you go with 1 `<script>`/marquee, you don't need the for loop.

Comment: To simplify things a bit: ***a)*** remove all ids from marquee divs, ***b)*** remove all individual init scripts from each tab. ***c)*** give each of your marquee divs the same class: `marquee`. ***d)*** place the JS script [from here](https://codepen.io/andrei-gheorghiu/pen/eoXmGy) into your page (inside a `<script>` tag), at the bottom of the page. Should work smoothly.

Comment: Each marquee does have the same class ```marquee``` but I see now that something is changing the published classes to be ```marquee0```, ```marquee1```, etc. I'm working from here: https://preview.webflow.com/preview/pizza-heroes?utm_source=pizza-heroes&preview=36a852439c42450062d5ef528e53b1c2

Comment: I really fucked up this question with all these edits didn't I? Oh well, I'll try again and will follow the rules better next time.

Comment: I see now what you mean by the changed class. It's the script that dies it. When I looked at your website, I had no way of knowing the source. Another proof code should be in the question. Unfortunately, SO is slower to respond to reopen requests. But I'm hoping I helped you fix your problem, at least. Happy coding!

Comment: Another note: since you already include the marquee script from `https://codepen.io/ali-z/pen/XQoVQQ.js`, there's no reason to place it in the JS section as well. Some scripts, if included more than once, conflict with themselves. Not this one, though.